# Isomorphism type of Galois group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Find the splitting field $\mathbb K$, the isomorphism type of the Galois group Gal$(\mathbb K / \mathbb Q)$, and the action of its generators on $\mathbb K$ for $x^3 + 3$ (from $\mathbb Q [x]$)

Corollary: Let $K$ be a ﬁeld, $f ∈ K[x]$ and let $L$ be the splitting ﬁeld for $f$ over $K$. Write $f$ as $ag_1^{s_1}  g_2 ^{s_2} ···g_k^{s_k}$ , where $a ∈ K$ and all $g_i ∈ K[x]$ are monic irreducible and pairwise diﬀerent. (Since all $g_i$ are monic, $a$ is the leading coeﬃcient of $f$). Let $R$ be the set of roots of $f$ in $L$, and $R_i$ be the set of roots of $g_i, i = 1,...,k$. Then

1. $\{R_i|1 ≤ i ≤ k\}$ is a partition of $R$; and
2. the orbits of Gal$(L/K)$ on $R$ are precisely the sets $R_1,...,R_k$.

---

$\mathbb K =\mathbb Q (3^{1/3} \xi , 3^{1/3} \xi^3, 3^{1/3} \xi^5 )$

$G=\text{Gal} (\mathbb K / \mathbb Q)$ acts faithfully of the set of roots of the given polynomial. Since our given polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ (doesn't have any roots in $\mathbb Q$), by the corollary, $G$ has one orbit namely $R=\{3^{1/3} \xi , 3^{1/3} \xi^3, 3^{1/3} \xi^5 \}$.

Action of its generators:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
        \hline
        ~        & 3^{1/3} \xi   & 3^{1/3} \xi ^3  & 3^{1/3} \xi ^5\\ \hline
        \alpha_1 & 3^{1/3} \xi & 3^{1/3} \xi ^3 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^5 \\ 
        \alpha_2 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^3 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^5 & 3^{1/3} \xi  \\ 
        \alpha_3 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^5  & 3^{1/3} \xi & 3^{1/3} \xi ^3 \\ 
\alpha_4 & 3^{1/3} \xi   & 3^{1/3} \xi^5 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^3 \\ 
\alpha_5 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^5  & 3^{1/3} \xi^3 & 3^{1/3} \xi  \\ 
\alpha_6 & 3^{1/3} \xi ^3  & 3^{1/3} \xi & 3^{1/3} \xi ^5 \\ 
                \hline
    \end{matrix}
$$

I don't know if I have done the above right but all the elements seem to have order three. So the isomorphism type must be something to do with $C_3$...

Please can someone say if I have done the above correct and help me with the isomorphism type part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you've called $\xi$ above but to avoid confusion, I'm going to take $\zeta$ to be a primitive cube root of unity. Then the roots are $-3^{1/3},-\zeta 3^{1/3}, -\zeta^2 3^{1/3}$, noting that $(-1)^3=-1$.

If you know what the degree of the splitting field is, then you know the size of the Galois group which should limit the possible isomorphism types. Furthermore, since the Galois group acts on $|R|$ elements, it must embed into the symmetric group on $|R|$ elements which limits your options even further.

Now you are right that since the polynomial is irreducible you have an orbit of size $3$ and hence an element of order $3$ (NB this is only true as $3$ is prime). Can you spot another, rather classical Galois automorphism here though?

Comment: Sorry, yeah $\xi = e^{\frac{\pi}3i}$. I think the degree of the splitting field is $6$ so the isomorphism type is either $C_6$ or $C_3 \times C_2$ right? I am not sure about what you are saying about the classical Galois automorphism...

Comment: $C_6$ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_3$. There's a nonabelian group of order 6 as well.

Comment: OK so have I done my table correct???

Comment: Where did your $\alpha_i$ come from?

Comment: they are just the automorphisms

Comment: My point is your telling me the splitting field has degree $6$ (which is right), so you should have $6$ automorphisms. Whilst your table is right, it is incomplete.

Comment: OH I see! But how do we determine whether it is $C_6$ or $C_2 \times C_2$? The order of the roots seem to be $3$ right?

Comment: Firstly, the two groups of order $6$ are $C_6$ and $S_3$. As I explained above, the Galois group must embed into $S_3$ and so must be isomorphic to $S_3$ here.

Comment: Complex conjugation is the classical automorphism I was referring to - how does this act on your roots and what order does it have?

Comment: i don't get how you came to the conclusion that it must embed into $S_3$... how did you know that

Comment: Any Galois automorphism must send a root to another root and so by labelling the roots each automorphism will correspond to an element of $S_3$.

Comment: I see. This might be a stupid question but why CAN'T it be $C_6$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37140/discussion-between-matt-b-and-snowman).